# ¿Qué significa 'conde' (El burlador de Sevilla​ de Tirso de Molina)?

Tags: significado, significado-en-contexto

En la jornada primera [*El burlador de Sevilla*](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/El_burlador_de_Sevilla/Acto_I)​ de Tirso de Molina, Catalinón dice:

> Es hijo aqueste señor
> del camarero mayor
> del rey, por quien ser espero
> antes de seis días **conde**
> en Sevilla, donde va,
> y adonde su alteza está,
> si a mi amistad corresponde.

¿Qué significa *[conde](https://dle.rae.es/conde?m=form)* aquí? No puedo [resolver](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/conde) esto.

Comment: rta: conde es lo que el tipo quiere ser, eso es todo

Comment: No he leido la obra ni estoy familiarizado con Tirso de Molina pero creo que ahí correspondería la primera acepción del DLE que enlazas: 1. m. y f. Persona con el título nobiliario inmediatamente inferior al de marqués. Si reordenamos un poco: "por quien espero ser conde antes de seis días en Sevilla"; es decir, el narrador espera que el hijo del camarero mayor le haga conde o le ayude a serlo (convenza al rey).

Answer (score -1):

Pudiera ser el título nobiliario de Conde.